# SQLiteConstraintException cause stopping Activity. How can I avoid it?

Tags: java, android

I have an application which can insert records into a table. The table has a primary key. (licensePlace). I get a SQLiteConstraintException when I try to insert a record whose licensePlace is already exist in the database.

I want to handle this exception in the following way:
In this case the user should get an alertDialog and inform him that the licensePlace is not correct.

My problem is that SQLiteConstraintException cause stopping the Activity and I don't know how can I avoid this.

Comment: Did you try adding an alert in the catch block of the exception?

Comment: Can you post how you're handling the error now?

Answer (score 0):

First of all by definition you can not enter a row who's key value already exists in the DB.

Secondly, you could either test prior to attempting the insert to see if that key value already exists (pretty simple query WHERE column = value). 
Alliteratively, you could place it in a try catch statement and handle the error yourself.

I would recommend the former.